# Call multi-quoted unix command in python's subprocess

Tags: python, unix

How do i call a unix command such as `df -Ph | awk 'NR>=2 {print $6","$5","$4}'` using subprocess. Would it make sense to use shlex.split here?

Thanks for any assistance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a pipe, so it needs to run in the shell. So just use the string form and make sure to specify `shell=True`. As for the quoting, it's easiest to use a triple quote here:

```
cmd = """df -Ph | awk 'NR>=2 {print $6","$5","$4}'"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have `subprocess` pass it to a shell by setting `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.call('''df -Ph | awk 'NR>=2 {print $6","$5","$4}'''', shell=True)
```

Comment: Worked with the triple double quotes - as shown in Kindalls solution -  instead of the single. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can also do like this. Do not forget to import sub-process

```
import subprocess
def linuxOperation():
 p = subprocess.Popen(["df","-Ph"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 p2 = subprocess.Popen(["awk",'NR>=2 {print $6","$5","$4}'], stdin=p.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
 p.stdout.close()
 out,err = p2.communicate()
 print(out)


 linuxOperation()
```